# joomla site urls not redirecting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, joomla

I have a website made in Joomla that has a button that is supposed to redirect to a Wordpress page.

```
<p><a href="https://forms.site.ca/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%2F" target="_blank">Questionnaire</a></p>
```

The button is supposed to go to https://forms.site.ca/ but the page then goes back to http://site.ca/?login=empty but site.ca is the site with the button.

Not sure why but any advise is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What does " ?redirect_to=%2F " do?

Comment: It was the url the site would show when I manually went to forms.site.ca  I think I figured it out though

Comment: Just remove that piece, i don't believe that it's good for something

Comment: Doesn't work no matter what url I try...

Comment: Is the website currently live so that i can see it?If so, what is the url?

Comment: I figured it out...thank you all for your help...issue with wrong plugin being used

Comment: Sounds like a redirect issue on the target site and not with Joomla, I also assume that the %2 is there to be replaced with something. If that is the case be sure that the contents of that isn't something that the target doesn't like. Using Chrome's dev tools for example you can use the network log to see exactly whats going on https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading?hl=en .

Also Apache, Nginx and other popular servers have request log you could look at too

Just saw your reply N D, be sure to put your answer in here and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

" wp-login.php?redirect_to=%2F " means "page_login.php redirect to= nothing but a space " so this part need to be removed or modified.
the href should be "https://forms.site.ca/" to go to the good page.

and if you want a connexion you can use a general user and fill the parameters in url directly.
Go on the wordpress codex to know the parameters to add.

https://www.google.fr/search?q=wp-login.php%3Fredirect&oq=wp-login.php%3Fredirect&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.1102187j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8